# RegEx - How to get if a path is the same as another path or it is a subdirectory

Tags: php, regex, directory, subdirectory

path

```
c:\d\e\f
```

other paths to be compared with the path:

```
c:\d\e\f // true
c:\d\e\f\g // true
c:\d\e\f\g\h // true
c:\d\e // false
c:\d\e\q // false
c:\d\q // false
c:\d // false
```

How can I achieve it with RegEx?

Comment: Why regex, when all you'd need to do here is check if one string _starts with_ the other ...?

Answer (score -1):

```
REGEX: /c:\\d\\e\\f/i
```

You can test here: https://regexr.com/

Put `/c:\\d\\e\\f/i` in the expression field
and this in the text field:

```
c:\d\e\f
c:\d\e\f\g
c:\d\e\f\g\h
c:\d\e
c:\d\e\q
c:\d\q
c:\d
```

It will show you what matches and what does not.  Only the first 3 will match.  Note I added flag `i`, so your pattern is case insensitive (since Windows uses `C:` often.